# Why does my input id not connect to 'for' from the label to check the checkbox without html?

Tags: html, checkbox

I want my checkbox to be able to be checked without using and JS. I think you do this by putting an ID to input and connecting it to the for in the label. This however does not work.

This is my HTML:

```html
<label for="burger" class="hamburgerMenu" href="#">&#8801;</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="burger" />
```

Comment: use `checked` in your input tag like this ->  <input type="checkbox" id="burger" checked />.
`checked specifies that an <input> element should be pre-selected (checked) when the page loads.`

Comment: I'm sorry, you understood me wrong. I do not want it preselected on the page. I want the user to be able to select it and un select it on his own will. I know there is a way to do this without javascript but it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Well my bad, but what you want your code is already doing that, I can see it's working

Comment: Yes you're right. I just tried it in a different file and it worked. I also just noticed that i cannot click the links in the same navigation as the checkbox. So the whole navigation might be broken. Any idea what could've happened?

Comment: by links, did you mean your menu? also I am not clear what exactly you want. please update your code with desired output